# Return invalid value when Implement the bind Function of Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement the *Function.prototype.bind* in javascript,
But the final return is undefined when call *getMethond*

```js
const testObj = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function(a,b) {
   return [this.x,a,b];
  }
};
Function.prototype.myBind = function (obj,...arg) {
  const self = this;
  return function(){
    self.apply(obj,arg);
  }
};
const getMethond = testObj.getX.myBind(testObj,100,200);
console.log(getMethond()); //undefined
```

Other ways, when use *console.log* it is ok;

```js
const testObj = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function(a,b) {
   console.log(this.x,a,b);
  }
};
Function.prototype.myBind = function (obj,...arg) {
  const self = this;
  return function(){
    self.apply(obj,arg);
  }
};
const getMethond = testObj.getX.myBind(testObj,100,200);
getMethond();
```

I don't know why this is, who can explain it briefly, thank you！

Comment: The returned function isn't returning anything. Put a `return` in front of `self.apply`

Answer (score 2):

Notice your original code:

```
Function.prototype.myBind = function (obj, ...arg) {
  const self = this;
  return function(){
    self.apply(obj, arg);
  }
}
```

That basically returns a function.

So when you execute:

```
const getMethod = testObj.getX.myBind(testObj,100,200);
```

The value of `getMethod` is actually approximately translated to:

```
function(){
  testObj.getX(100, 200);
  // Originally: self.apply(obj, arg), where:
  // `self` is `getX`
  // `obj` is `testObj`
  // `arg` is [100, 200]
}
```

Now, knowing that, when you run `getMethod()`, nothing gets returned, because there isn't a `return` statement in the value of `getMethod`, which is why you get `undefined`.

**What you should do**

```js
const testObj = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function(a,b) {
   return [this.x,a,b];
  }
};

Function.prototype.myBind = function (obj,...arg) {
  const self = this;
  return function(){
    return self.apply(obj,arg);
  /*^^^^^^*/
  }
};

const getMethod = testObj.getX.myBind(testObj, 100, 200);

console.log(getMethod());
```

Now, the value of `getMethod` is approximately translated to:

```
function(){
  return testObj.getX(100, 200);
}
```

By calling it, you return `testObj.getX()`, which returns `[this.x, a, b]`.